# High speed Capture request Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm having some issues setting up a capture request for high speed video. I intend to capture at 120 FPS on Nexus 6P. I set the minimum API to 23, since I don't plan to deploy this app to any other phone.

Where I'm not quite understanding is how to get my capture request to work. Right now, I'm doing my best to change up the code within Camera2Video sample in google's samples. [Link to sample from Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video)

Here is all of the relevant code:

```
private void startPreview() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        setUpMediaRecorder();
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>();

        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
        surfaces.add(previewSurface);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

        mCameraDevice.createConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        //mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                //mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                mPreviewSession2 = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


/**
 * Update the camera preview. {@link #startPreview()} needs to be called in advance.
 */
private void updatePreview() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(mPreviewBuilder);
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("CameraPreview");
        thread.start();
        mPreviewBuilder2 =  mPreviewSession2.createHighSpeedRequestList(mPreviewBuilder.build());
        //mPreviewBuilder2 =


        //mPreviewSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewBuilder.build(), null, mBackgroundHandler);
        mPreviewSession.setRepeatingBurst(mPreviewBuilder2, null, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void setUpCaptureRequestBuilder(CaptureRequest.Builder builder) {
    builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
    Range<Integer> fpsRange = Range.create(120, 120);
    builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, fpsRange);

}
```

I have no problem getting the code to updatepreview. Unfortunately, from there I've hit a roadblock on how to give setRepeatingBurst my capture requests. I know the constructor is different from the sample's setRepeatingRequest. Therefore, I need to find a way to give setRepeatingBurst my surfaces, my CONTROL_MODE request and my TARGET_FPS_RANGE request.

```
/**
 * Camera preview.
 */
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewBuilder;
List<CaptureRequest> mPreviewBuilder2;

/**
 * A reference to the current {@link android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession} for
 * preview.
 */
private CameraCaptureSession mPreviewSession;
private CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession mPreviewSession2;
```

Any help figuring out how to make this work correctly would be very helpful. I haven't found much on the net in order to help and there isn't any article in StackOverflow mentioning any of the highspeed capture functions. My largest issue here is trying to understand how createConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession gives a CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession session. So that I can use the createHighSpeedRequestList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but solved it using your question.

In your case I think it should work if you call

```
mPreviewSession2.setRepeatingBurst(mPreviewBuilder2, null, mBackgroundHandler);
```

instead of

```
mPreviewSession.setRepeatingBurst(mPreviewBuilder2, null, mBackgroundHandler);
```

since you are then setting the RepeatingBurst on the CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession

---

I made a github repository showing how to create a highspeed recording session using camera2 api.

https://github.com/thesleort/Android-Slow-Motion-Camera2.git

Comment: sometimes it helps using more explainatory names for your variables.

Comment: what phone did you use?

Comment: I don't have access to it right now, but I managed to get it working. I can put it on a git repository later this week, and then link it here :)

Comment: I will push it to this https://github.com/thesleort/Android-Slow-Motion-Camera2.git

Comment: I have added the important files to the repository. Keep in mind that it is not compilable, and should therefore be implemented in your own program for testing.

Comment: By default it I made it so that it will choose the highest available fps for the chosen resolution. However, if you want to change it explicitly, you can un-comment line 635 and "comment" line 636.

When you run the app, it will print the available fps-ranges. You can choose from any of these. On my Nexus 6P it the following ranges are available: [30,120],[30,240],[120,240],[240,240].

The first number is the preview framerate, and the last number is the capturing framerate.

Comment: Now when you try to play the movie, you it will play it in normal speed (no slow motion). You will have to tell the player to play the movie at a lower speed.

Comment: This is kind of a noobie question but if I wanted to run processing on the preview frames would that be possible? How would I go about doing it?

Comment: So you want to run the do something with the frames you've captured, while still capturing?

Comment: Yes exactly. In fact capturing as a video doesnt even interest me. I need to process the frames at 120 fps.

Comment: I guess it would be possible, if you do that in another thread. When you start recording, a video file will appear in the chosen directory. You can access this ever-increasing video while recording. If you then have some framework to modify/edit the video, you should be able to do so. Keep in mind that this would require a lot of memory bandwidth, as the phone is also using this for the camera. You might run in to some bottleneck with highspeed capture and editing at the same time. ofc all this is hardware dependent, so the result might vary from device to device.